# Form works on desktop browser but not mobile browser

Tags: php, jquery, html, mobile, browser

I've checked the web but nothing really compares to this **exact** issue, hence this question is being asked.

I have a register form. It works on my laptop and desktop PC however faces issues when testing on a mobile device. I have tried it with many mobile devices and they all seem to redirect to 'mywebsite.com/#'. The main issue here is that I should receive an error stating that their are blank fields (Just as it does on the browser) however it seems as if mobile devices just simply get redirected with a hashtag and ignore the error warning.

I think it's something to do with JQuery possibly but I do not know for certain.

```
<form id="registerrform" action="#" method="post" class="registerbox">
   <div id="registerrerrors"></div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $sn['lang']['username'];?>"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $sn['lang']['email_address'];?>"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $sn['lang']['password'];?>"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="confirmpass" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $sn['lang']['confirm_password'];?>"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">
         <option value="male"><?php echo $sn['lang']['male'];?></option>
         <option value="female"><?php echo $sn['lang']['female'];?></option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <center>
      <button type="submit" name="registerrgo" id="registerrgo" class="btn btn-success sign-up">Sign up</button>
   </center>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting, with `<form action="#">` in your HTML?

Comment: It's the same as redirecting it back to the actual page. The reason for this is because if the form is correct (No errors so the user has successfully registered) then that hashtag is ignored and the user is redirected to another welcome page. If however their are errors, an error message shows up.