# Browser image upload works, but not mobile browser

Tags: vue.js, api-platform.com, symfony5

I am having a similar problem as described below.

I have a site made in VueJS, backend is symfony PHP.
php.ini allows 16M uploads
a VueJS component for the upload: "vue-picture-input": "^2.1.6",

And the relevant config:
accept="image/jpeg,image/png" size="16"

However, when I upload from desktop it works, image is saved. When I upload from a mobile browser it does not.

[Form works on desktop browser but not mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032186/form-works-on-desktop-browser-but-not-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0):

In the end the post on the attached link was correct. The mobile is more strict about the content type